# How to focus this popup window?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to focus on this popup window )"hasFocus". Addictionaly it works now only without popup. This popup works only when window isn't entire loaded for 1 second and fast click to different place. Here is main PHP code for this: pastebin.com/LNLuYqT3. Important popup window: pastebin.com/vc6sNxGz.

```
    function browsing(win, datapost)
    {
        var closed = false;
        exchange = getCookie('exchange<?php echo Encryption::decode(get("sid")); ?>');
        if(exchange == 'no' )
        {
            $.ajax({
                url : "<?php _router("exchange_process", array("uid" => get("uid"), "sid" => get("sid"))); ?>",
                type: "POST",
                data : datapost,
                success: function(res)
                {
                    var data = res[0];
                    var time   = Math.floor(data["duration"])*1000;
                    var duration = Math.floor(data["duration"]);
                    var url    = data["url"];
                    var browse = data["browse"];
                    var points = data["points"];
                    win = win;
                    if(data["open_status"] == false)
                    {
                        setCookie('exchange<?php echo Encryption::decode(get("sid")); ?>', 'yes');
                        win.close();
                    }
                    win.location = url;
                    progress(duration);
                    countdown("realtime_progress_counter", duration);
                    $("#realtime_url").html(data["show_url"]);
                    $("#realtime_points").html(points);
                    if(win || !win.closed)
                    {
                        window.setTimeout(function(){
                            closed = true;
                            if (win || !win.closed) {
                                newdatapost = 'browse='+browse;
                                browsing(win, newdatapost);
                            }else{
                                closed = false;
                            }
                        }, time);
                    }
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    $('#exchange_alert').html('<b>'+app_network_error+'</b>');
                }
            });
        }
        var checkopen = setInterval(function() {
            if (!win || win.closed) {
                if(!closed)
                {
                    $("#realtime_progress").children('.progress-bar').css('width', '0%');
                    setCookie('exchange<?php echo Encryption::decode(get("sid")); ?>', 'yes');
                    clear_session('<?php _get("sid"); ?>', '<?php _router("browsing_process", array("uid" => get("uid"), "sid" => get("sid"))); ?>', false);
                    window.location = "<?php _router("browsing_process", array("uid" => get("uid"), "sid" => get("sid"))); ?>";
                    clearInterval(checkopen);
                }
            }
        }, 500);

        <?php if(s("exchange/focus")=="yes") { ?>
        var checkfocus = setInterval(function(){
        if(win)
        {
            var focused = win.document.hasFocus();
            if(!focused)
            {
                setCookie('exchange<?php echo Encryption::decode(get("sid")); ?>', 'yes');
                win.close();
                clear_session('<?php _get("sid"); ?>', '<?php _router("browsing_process", array("uid" => get("uid"), "sid" => get("sid"))); ?>', true);
                clearInterval(checkfocus);
            }
        }
        }, 500);
        <?php } ?>
        $('#StopBrowsing').on('click', function(event) {
            setCookie('exchange<?php echo Encryption::decode(get("sid")); ?>', 'yes');
            win.close();
            clear_session('<?php _get("sid"); ?>', '<?php _router("browsing_process", array("uid" => get("uid"), "sid" => get("sid"))); ?>', true);
        });
    }

    $('#Browsing').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      exchange = getCookie('exchange<?php echo Encryption::decode(get("sid")); ?>');
      $('#exchange_alert').html('<div class="alert alert-danger" ><b style="color: white" ><?php _l("browsing_hint"); ?></b></div>');
          var win = $.popupWindow('<?php _router("browsing_process", array("uid" => get("uid"), "sid" => get("sid"))); ?>?start=true', {
          name: 'surfow_browsing',
          scrollbars:  true,
          width: screen.width,
          height: screen.height,
          center: 'screen',
          onLoad: function() {
              if(exchange == 'yes' || exchange == '' || exchange == null)
              {
                setCookie('exchange<?php echo Encryption::decode(get("sid")); ?>', 'no');
                browsing(win, '');
                $('#Browsing').hide();
                $('#StopBrowsing').show();
              }
          }
      });
    });
  });
  $(document).ready(function() {
      exchange = getCookie('exchange<?php echo Encryption::decode(get("sid")); ?>');
      if(exchange == 'no')
      {
          $('#Browsing').hide();
          $('#exchange_alert').html("<div class=\"alert alert-info fg-white\" ><?php _l("browsing_start_hint"); ?> <a href='javascript::void(0)' class=\"btn btn-primary\" id='Refresh'><?php _l("refresh"); ?></a></div>");
      }
      $('#Refresh').on('click', function(event) {
          <?php if(s("exchange/openmode")=="popup") { ?>
          win = window.open("", 'surfow_browsing');
          win.close();
          <?php } ?>
          setCookie('exchange<?php echo Encryption::decode(get("sid")); ?>', 'yes');
          window.location = "<?php _router("browsing_process", array("uid" => get("uid"), "sid" => get("sid"))); ?>";
      });
  });
</script>
```

And here the buttons: https://pastebin.com/FnryFJh8.

Comment: `win = win;` guess you are really making sure it is set to win.

Comment: You are so generous to add in an undocumented PHP code redenering a JavaScript code. How about you give us the list of code what PHP displays?